# I have a simple web service in .Net Core 2.1 . I want to post from Unity 3D but it does not work

Tags: c#, .net, json, web-services, unity-game-engine

I would like to post from Unity3d to a web service (RESTFUL) based on .Net Core 2.1.
GET works, POST not.

I received

> {
>       "": [
>           "Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path '', line 1, position 1."
>       ]
>   }

I tried to change also RequestHeader but it is not working.

By using a separate .Net client the following code worked.

```
HttpClient().PostAsJsonAsync(weblink,SerializedData)
```

what "magic" is behind PostAsJsonAsync ?

Into Unity3D I cannot use the extensions for HttpClient.

This is the code into Unity3d

```
    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(postUnityWebRequest());
    }

    IEnumerator postUnityWebRequest()
    {
        ///<summary>
        /// Post using UnityWebRequest class
        /// </summary>
        var jsonString = "{\"Id\":3,\"Name\":\"Roy\"}";
        byte[] byteData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(jsonString.ToCharArray());

        UnityWebRequest unityWebRequest = new UnityWebRequest("http://localhost:2071/api/Commands?Id=1", "POST");
        unityWebRequest.uploadHandler = new UploadHandlerRaw(byteData);

        unityWebRequest.method = UnityWebRequest.kHttpVerbPOST;
        unityWebRequest.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        unityWebRequest.SetRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json"); 
        yield return unityWebRequest.SendWebRequest();

        if (unityWebRequest.isNetworkError || unityWebRequest.isHttpError)
        {
            Debug.Log(unityWebRequest.error);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Form upload complete! Status Code: " + unityWebRequest.responseCode);
        }
    }
```

This is the code for the web Service.

```
namespace WebService.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]


    public class CommandsController : ControllerBase
    {

        private static List<string> commandToBeExecuted = new List<string>();

        // GET: api/Commands
        [HttpGet]
        public string Get()
        {
            if (commandToBeExecuted.Count > 0)
            {
                string output = commandToBeExecuted.First();
                commandToBeExecuted.RemoveAt(0);
                return output;
            }

            return "-1";

        }

        // GET: api/Commands/5
        [HttpGet("{id}", Name = "Get")]
        public string Get(int id)
        {
            return "value";
        }

        // POST: api/Commands
        [HttpPost]
        public void Post([FromBody] string value)
        {
            commandToBeExecuted.Add(value);
        }

        // PUT: api/Commands/5
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody] string value)
        {
            int debugShouldStopHere = 0;
        }

        // DELETE: api/ApiWithActions/5
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: It seems `SerializedData` has invalid data. Can you show it? (Or at least the beginning?)

Comment: HttpClient().PostAsJsonAsync(weblink,SerializedData) is the call that worked into another client. The data that don't work are in the function   IEnumerator postUnityWebRequest()

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misread :-/

Comment: I think it's the encoding. `ASCII`is a bit outdated (although systems should be backward compatible) Can you try: `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(...)`?

Comment: No ; ( not working

Comment: Ok, it seems a parser error. Can be on sending or retrieval. Please post http status code and full response if the send is successful. Please show the json string otherwise.

Comment: I'm now debugging the webserver and I'm using PostMan to check the functionality. The Get is fine. When I POST I get this from the service       ```Connection id "0HLM6AG9T7IBI", Request id "0HLM6AG9T7IBI:00000001": the application completed without reading the entire request body   ```                             I'm, sending the following body```{
    "id": "12",
    "test":"test"
}```
 with header application/json .  Really I'm going crazy for this stupid issue! Postman get the answer ```"": ["The input was not valid."]}```

Comment: I know this can be frustrating ;-) ... I do have another option: your post contains a `string`, if you post json it expects a `complex type` aka, a `class`

Comment: it expects string [FromBody] string value

Comment: I also see that I setup PostMan wrongly withouth header. If I set up correctly the header . and I have this code to post: ```POST /api/Commands HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:2071
Content-Type: application/json
cache-control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 5d65d0c1-728b-4196-92a6-7d8d5be65b7e
{
    "id": "12",
    "test":"test"
}
 ------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--```    THEN the reply I get is: ```{
    "": [
        "Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path '', line 1, position 1."
    ]
}```

Comment: Ah, yes I was mistaken. It expects a string. Nevertheless, you will have some model binders in you pipeline by default doing some magic stuff. Although, you are right, it shouldn't interfere

Comment: However, if you create a class, `class Foo { public string Id ...` etc, it might just work.

Comment: Ok... I will try more... but the complete request is the one before and I just pass id  and test...

Comment: It starts to work when I changed the POST with passing a custom serialized object.        `public Command Post([FromBody]Command value)`   weird that with simple string it didn't work!

Comment: Well, in a way it does make sense: you are posting as json, not as plain text. The receiver sees this and expects a method, similar to the data structure you provided. But then, in your action there is no property to map to.